# Tamaño de un directorio en C# [System.UnauthorizedAccessException ]

Tags: c#

Necesito ayuda al calcular el tamaño de un directorio en C#.

Me da el siguiente error "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" al leer el tamaño de un directorio de un usuario por las carpetas bloqueadas en "Appdata" NTUSER,etc...

Existe alguna forma de omitir los errores de permisos?
No necesito que me calcule el tamaño de las carpetas que estan bloqueadas.

Muchas gracias!

```
static long GetDirectorySize(string p)
{

    // 1.
    // Get array of all file names.
    string[] a = Directory.GetFiles(p, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    // 2.
    // Calculate total bytes of all files in a loop.
    long b = 0;
    foreach (string name in a)
    {
        // 3.
        // Use FileInfo to get length of each file.
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(name);
        b += info.Length;
    }
    // 4.
    // Return total size
    return b;      

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon un `try-catch`

Comment: Mejor ponle el flag `IgnoreInaccessible`

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Donde añado el flag?
Llevo una semana solo con C#, disculpa la ignorancia.

Comment: Pero ese flag es de .Net 6. Añade un try-catch. Sabes cómo hacerlo? Pon el código fuente y te ayudo

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich
Muchísimas gracias!
Te lo copio en un clipboard online por la limitación de caracteres.


https://cl1p.net/uqzbawlhysidp

Comment: Trata de colocarlo en la pregunta porque son las reglas del juego SO. Estuve viendo y necesitas en vez de Directory.GetFiles tienes que cambiarlo por DirectoryInfo

Comment: Solo pega ese metodo

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich
Lamento mi torpeza pero no es posible reemplazar ese metodo tal cual.
Podrias corregirme el codigo o añadirme al codigo que ya tenia el try/catch?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No voy  a reemplazar el metodo solo la instrucción. En vez de GetFiles se tiene que utilizar EnumerateFiles para poder utilizar el try-catch y sobrepasar los  archivos que no tienes acceso. No se puede utilizar el try-catch con el GetFiles por no podrías leer nada.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Funciona, y me muestra el tamaño del directorio, pero de forma erronea.
Me muestra 12MB y es un directorio con 136GB.

Comment: Es por tu variable `b`   que es de tipo  `long`. Quizá si la cambias a  `double` te muestre el valor correcto o en todo caso acumula en Kb o Mb. Estás acumulando el tamaño en  bytes. Podrías dividir el tamaño del archivo , por ejemplo, entre 1024  y acumular ese resultado. Puedes utilizar también `System.UInt64` o `ulong`

Comment: Aunque debería contenerlo

Answer (score 3):

Para  ignorar el `UnauthorizedAccessException`  debes poner un  `try-catch` para capturar la excepción antedicha, sin embargo, no la podemos capturar si utilizamos `Directory.GetFiles` ya que ésta carga todos los archivos en el arreglo antes de continuar  con la  siguiente instrucción y por lo tanto, no podriamos leer  ningún archivo.

En lugar de `Directory.GetFiles` utilizaremos la clase `DirectoryInfo` que nos devolverá un objeto con información del directorio y utilizamos el metodo `EnumerateFiles` para leer todos los archivos. Esta ultima a diferencia de `GetFiles`  va trayendo archivo por archivo y por lo tanto, aquí si podemos capturar la excepción e ignorarla. Aparte  que `EnumerateFiles` nos trae  ya el `FileInfo`.

El método quedaría asi:

*EDICION*

```
static long GetDirectorySize(string p)
{
       DirectoryInfo dirP = new DirectoryInfo(p);
       long b = 0;
       try
       {
           foreach (var fi in dirP.EnumerateFiles())
           {
               try
               {
                   b += fi.Length;
               }
               catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
               {
                //   Debug.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
               }
           }

           foreach (var di in dirP.EnumerateDirectories("*"))
           {
               try
               {
                   foreach (var fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                   {
                       try
                       {
                           b += fi.Length;
                       }
                       catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                       {
                        //   Debug.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
                       }
                   }
               }
               catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
               {
                 //  Debug.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
               }
           }
       }
       catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
       {
         //  Debug.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
       }


        //    Debug.WriteLine(b);
         //   Debug.WriteLine(bb.ToString());

       return b;

   }
```

Esta solución es para .NET 4.x.  Si utilizas  la versión .NET 6 puedes hacer el `GetFiles`utilizando el  flag `IgnoreInaccessible`.